# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debbuger's target code type is

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, directx-11

Intro: Code does not work in Release mode. Works in Debug.

This shows on one of my breakpoints:

[image: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debbuger's target code type is]

Code spot is:

```
void Font::operator<<(std::string s)
{
    this->printf(s); // this line
}
```

This method is called like this:

```
float oneframe;
oneframe = (double)elapsed/ 1000000.0;

float ffps =1. / oneframe;
int fps = ffps;
char txt[200];
sprintf(txt, "%d FPS", fps);
font << txt; // displays text
```

Printf is:

```
void Font::printf(std::string s)
{
    UINT lines = 0;
    std::vector<float> offsetX;
    float offsetY=0;
    UINT length = s.size();
    XMMATRIX M = XMMatrixScaling(m_scaling.x, m_scaling.y, m_scaling.z)*
        XMMatrixTranslation(m_translation.x, m_translation.y, m_translation.z);
    float fontLength=0;
    float fontHeight = 60.0f / windowHeight;
    float fontWidth = 60.0f / windowWidth * 0.6f;

    m_deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, 0, 0);
    m_deviceContext->IASetInputLayout(m_inputLayout);
    m_deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, 0, 0);
    m_deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_texture);
    m_deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_sampler);
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_dsOff, 1);

    if (m_anchor != TOP_LEFT) 
    {
        float offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            offset += m_kerning*widthMap[s[i]];
            if (s[i] == '\n' || s[i] == '\r' || i == length - 1)
            {
                offsetX.push_back(offset);
                offset = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        XMFLOAT3 TL(-1, 1, 0), BR(1, -1, 0);
        XMVECTOR vTL, vBR;
        if (s[i] == '\n' || s[i] == '\r')
        {
            fontLength = 0;
            lines++;
            continue;
        }
        switch (m_anchor)
        {
        default:
        case TOP_LEFT:
            vTL = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontLength, -m_leading*lines, 0)), M);
            vBR = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontWidth + fontLength, -m_leading*lines - fontHeight, 0)), M);
            break;
        case TOP_RIGHT:
            vTL = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontLength - offsetX[lines], -m_leading*lines, 0)), M);
            vBR = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontWidth + fontLength - offsetX[lines], -m_leading*lines - fontHeight, 0)), M);
            break;
        case BOTTOM_LEFT:
            offsetY = m_leading*offsetX.size();
            vTL = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontLength, -m_leading*lines+ offsetY, 0)), M);
            vBR = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontWidth + fontLength, -m_leading*lines - fontHeight+ offsetY, 0)), M);
            break;
        case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
            offsetY = m_leading*offsetX.size();
            vTL = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontLength - offsetX[lines], -m_leading*lines + offsetY, 0)), M);
            vBR = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontWidth + fontLength - offsetX[lines], -m_leading*lines - fontHeight + offsetY, 0)), M);
            break;
        case CENTER:
            {
                offsetY = m_leading*offsetX.size() / 2;
                float halfOffsetx = offsetX[lines] / 2;
                vTL = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontLength - halfOffsetx, -m_leading*lines + offsetY, 0)), M);
                vBR = XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&XMFLOAT3(fontWidth + fontLength - halfOffsetx, -m_leading*lines - fontHeight + offsetY, 0)), M);
                break; 
            }
        }
        XMStoreFloat3(&TL, vTL);
        XMStoreFloat3(&BR, vBR);
        assert(updateBuffer(TL, BR, fontMap[s[i]]));
        UINT stride, offset;
        stride = sizeof(SimpleVertex);
        offset = 0;
        m_deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
        m_deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
        m_deviceContext->Draw(6, 0);
        fontLength += m_kerning*widthMap[s[i]];
    }
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_dsOn, 1);
}
```

Here's where it gets weird. I get this notification while in Release mode. The code above completely works, in Debug. For whatever reason, it does not work when I switch to Release. I've checked the `txt`variable that is being sent to the function, it has text. To me, it seems as if the code has somehow been optimized out or something.

I have also deleted everything in the Debug and Release folders and did a fresh Build. Nothing. I've tested the executables without running from VS, same result. Debugging in Release shows that there is text in `txt` but I can't determine what happens as the debugger seems to float right over `font << txt`.

Comment: Most likely, in release build `Font::operator<<` got inlined, that's why you can't set the breakpoint on it. You would probably be able to set a breakpoing on the first line of `Font::printf` instead.

Comment: As an aside: You should really not pass ``std::string`` or ``std::wstring`` by value as it creates a lot of temporaries. Use ``const std::string& s`` instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah, I can view printf.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I'll try and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Been advised by the person who wrote the class I'm using that it's poo, and has too many problems. Will close this question.

Comment: It seems to me you have some property different on Debug and Release builds. Compare the Project properties between them **PAYING MUCH ATTENTION**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find out the answer. There is an `assert` used in printf near the end. Asserts do not run in Release. Only in debug.